# Как заменить значения между тегами?

Tags: python

Есть xml, в котором между тегами `<name>` текст такого вида `&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;`

```
import html
print(html.unescape('&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;')) #Привет
```

Вопрос. Как с помощью `re` применить операцию декодирования к каждому элементу между тегами `<name>..</name>`

```
(?<=name>).+?(?=</name) вот регулярка
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new_str = re.sub(регулярное_выражение, строка_замена, исходная_строка)`

Если вместо строки для замены передать туда функцию, она получит объект совпадения первым параметром. `Match.group(0)` — совпадение целиком (строка).

А совпавшая подстрока будет заменена на то, что вернет функция.

```
import html
import re

xml = '''
  <name>&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;</name>
  <name>&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;</name>
  <name>&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;</name>
'''

def replacer(match_obj):
    return html.unescape(match_obj.group(0))

xml = re.sub(r'(?<=name>).+?(?=</name)', replacer, xml)

print(xml)
```